# What does reshape on an image actually do?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What does the reshape below actually do in detail?

I have seen the sample tensorflow code but I'm not sure what the `(60000,28,28,1)` does, can anyone help to explain it in detail?

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()    
training_images=training_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/reshaping-of-data-for-deep-learning-using-keras as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reshaping your dataset in a multidimensional array with shapes `(60000,28,28,1)` which indicates:

1. You have 60000 samples of images
2. The images have the size of 28×28 (Width and height)
3. The number 1 indicates the number of channels. In this case you are using grayscale, so you only need one channel. If you need RGB you might use 3 instead.

When you load the MNIST dataset, you have a shape of `(60000, 28, 28)` which does not include the information of channels. What you did is just add this information to your dataset as another dimension of your array.